# Why do I get a continual messge "Not synced yet"?

Tags: outlook, synchronization

I run MS Outlook on my MS Lumia and my desktop.
My Lumia is trying to sync, but has been displaying a the message "Not synced yet" since I downloaded the last update on the PC.

Comment: Do you get any error code?

Comment: What type of account are you attempting to sync to?